# Return 1 if a person's name appears in a given day

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to create a column that returns the number 1 if a particular user's name appears one or more times in a given day and 0 if not. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

The best I could think of is something that resembles this:

```
SUM(IIF([User]= NULL,0,1))
```

Sample of Data:

```
Date             User            
1/9/2019          a               
1/9/2019          a               
1/9/2019          c               
2/9/2019          b               
2/9/2019          b
```

Desired output:

```
Date             User        Val       
1/9/2019          a           1     
1/9/2019          a           1    
1/9/2019          c           1    
2/9/2019          b           1   
2/9/2019          b           1
```

Comment: Your question is not completely clearly specified. As written, your calculation could just always return 1 to get your desired output. Can you describe a case when it would return 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to check for the particular day user exists or not? create a calculated field and add the condition as 
If [User] = Null then 0 else 1 end

place the calculated field in the view where you want to display.